# How to Set Home View in BIM 360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, bim

Is there a way to set BIM 360 3D views to all have the same home view? I tried setting it up inside Revit, and it works for my views when I open in Revit. But once I publish it and upload to BIM 360 it starts to create its own random home views. I've even tried to set the home views in BIM 360 itself with no luck. Would this be something I would have to fix using FORGE?

Answer (score 1):

Someone from AutoDesk was able to help me with this issue. What you're supposed to do is press "Save View in the view cube" to set the home view when uploading to BIM 360

[View Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKm87.png)

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer home views are copied from the CAD file definition, when using the Forge Viewer, you can change this Home View position by code. Unfortunately, when running in BIM360, you cannot inject your code like you would do with the Forge Viewer, so your only option is to get the Home View right in the CAD file.

Comment: The home view definition ssems to work fine in Revit, but in BIM 360 it seems to ignore that home definition set in Revit.

Could you send me a link of how to set the Home View position in Forge Viewer by code? Forge Viewer might be more useful for me in this case over BIM 360

Comment: The short answer is NOP_VIEWER.autocam.setHomeViewFrom(camera), but I'll write a more complete answer asap, but this will not work in BIM360 as you cannot run any of your code. You can only change it from the UI as "Coordination Specialist" said.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var a = viewer.getState({viewport})` to store viewport then use `viewer.restorestate(a)` apply when document loaded.